# Does "right back" have several meanings?

Tags: word-meaning

> We'll see you **right** back here tomorrow.

Is right used as an intensifier, emphasizing that we'll meet at this exact spot, not somewhere else?

> Leaning over, Pooh wrapped his arms around Christopher as far as they
> could go. Then he squeezed. Leaning down so Christopher could get a
> better angle, he squeezed Pooh **right** back.

Is right also used as an intensifier, emphasizing that Christopher was eager to return the embrace?

I only know one meaning of **right back**. If you say **I'll be right there** or **I'll be right back**, you mean that you will get to a place or get back to it in a very short time. But the above two sentences do not fit this meaning.

Comment: The second sentence fits the meaning perfectly: Pooh hugged Christophor and then immediately (i.e. "a very short time later") Christopher hugged Pooh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can mean different things in different contexts, but this use of 'right' always adds some kind of specificity.

*'Right back'* means **immediately**. In your example of "he squeezed Pooh right back" it means he immediately responded with a reciprocal squeeze.

*'Right here'* means **precisely** here. For example, if you were in a certain location, such as a building, and you said "here", you might be referring to the entire building. "Right here" could mean the specific spot within that building that you were pointing to or currently standing in.